# Combining Default Parameter and Parameter Sets

Tags: powershell, parameters, default

I have a PowerShell script that fetches data of a host specified in a csv, and if given a switch `reboot`, also tries to reboot the host. Therefore, and only in the case of a reboot, a credential is needed.

My parameter block looks like this:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName = 'None')] 
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [ValidateScript( {
      if ( -Not ($_ | Test-Path) ) {
        throw "Source $_ does not exist"
      }
      return $true
    })]
  $path= $(Join-Path $PWD.Path "sources.csv"),
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Extra', Mandatory = $false)]
  [switch]$reboot,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Extra', Mandatory = $true)]
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $credential = $(Get-Credential -UserName myUser)

)
```

My expectation: Only if `reboot` is given, the User is prompted for a credential.
But the credential popup is shown no matter what parameter is given.

I assume is has something to do with the default value.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your function? As it looks now, yes, your hunch is right. The default value prompts for credentials and will always prompt for credentials since that is n=how the value is defined, by an expression that prompts for credentials. If you have a variable with the command `Get-Credential -UserName myUser` it will prompt even without the variable being used as long as it is defined with that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Parameter Sets here at all. Simply make use of the Empty credential to initialize the `$credential` parameter with:

```
[CmdletBinding()] 
Param(
  [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
  [ValidateScript( {
      if ( -Not ($_ | Test-Path -PathType Leaf) ) {
            throw "Source $_ does not exist"
      }
    return $true
    })]
    $path = $(Join-Path $PWD.Path "sources.csv"),

    [switch]$reboot,

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty
)

# if no credential is given prompt for it
if ($credential -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) {
    $credential = Get-Credential -UserName myUser -Message 'Please enter your username and password'
}

# rest of your code goes here
```

Hope that helps